# What query string parameter is available for index.php, that works for both pages and blog articles?

Tags: php, query, slug

I have a page `/page1` and 2 articles `/article1` and `/another-article1`.

Which query string parameter for `index.php` is available to show the content?

I tried:

- `?p=` but

  - `index.php?p=page1` is working
  - `index.php?p=article1` displays a *search result page* showing the 2 articles **instead of just displaying `/article1`** (probably because they have `...article1...` in common in the slug?)
- `?page=`

  - `index.php?page=page1` is working but
  - `index.php?page=article1` is not working obviously because it's not a page

**Which parameter in `index.php?parameter=slug` would work to display both pages and articles?**

Comment: those parameters are the query variables, aka the parameters `WP_Query` uses as arguments. A quick look at the `WP_Query` documentation lists all arguments and what they do

Comment: also, what problem are you trying to solve by doing this? Can you provide some context? It will improve the answers you get and make it easier to understand yoour question